# SQL Server on remote computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Server Express instance on a computer with IP 192.168.66 on a home network.

I have enabled TCP/IP on port 49170 and added the incoming rule on Windows firewall.

I have an application that I want to install on different computers inside my network. When I am testing my application in Visual Studio, I am not able to connect to my instance on the remote computer.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EquipamentoDal.Properties.Settings.ExtinguisherMngConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.66,49170;Initial Catalog=ExtinguisherMng;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

The server name is `DESKTOP-HU51203\EXPRESS`. 
What i have done wrong to not be able to connect?

Comment: What is the exception? Can you ping the ip address from the remote PC?

Comment: You're using `Integrate security=true`, has the user rights enough in this computer? have you impersonted some user?

Comment: Integrated security probably won't work on a home network.

Comment: I am able to ping the computer yes.

Comment: and the connection string works fine on local instance ( on same machine) replacing IP,port by .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: try to telnet via port 49170 using cmd: `telnet 192.168.1.66 49170` can you connect to the server?

Comment: I am able to connect via telnet yes

Comment: which `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` are you using?

Comment: Windows authentication yes

Comment: Have you impesonate the current user? `<identity impersonate="true"/>`

Comment: SQL Server **Express** by default does **NOT** allow remote connections - have you explicitly enabled those remote connections on the SQL Server Express machine??

Comment: Yes remote connection is enabled

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string does not specify the Named Instance you're connecting to, it only specifies the IP address, which means any clients will connect to the default instance instead of a named instance.

By default SQL Server Express is configured differently to 'standard' versions of SQL Server (Standard, Workgroup, Developer, and  Enterprise Editions) as follows:

- Block incoming remote connections - this must be explictly enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Use a **Named Instance** called `SQLEXPRESS` instead of being configured as the **Default Instance**
- SQL Server Express is also unique in supporting `AttachDb` and `LocalDb` - the other SKUs/Editions do not support the `AttachDb` and `LocalDb` features.

In your case, you've already enabled Remote Connections and you're not using `AttachDb` or `LocalDb`, so you just need to configure your client to connect to a named instance:

You specify the named instance in your connection string using the format `<host>\<instance name>,<port>` in the `Data Source=` or `Server=` parameter, e.g. `Data Source=foo\SQLEXPRESS,1433`, or in your particular case:

```
Data Source=192.168.1.66\SQLEXPRESS,49170;Initial Catalog=ExtinguisherMng;Integrated Security=True
```

You mentioned that you're doing this on a Home network, which means it's unlikely you're using an Active Directory or Kerberos, and given SQL Server Express does not expose the passwords it uses for its Service Identity (nor can users authenticate as `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` over the network it means you cannot use `Integrated Security=True` (or `Integrated Security=SSPI` which is equivalent, but `SSPI` is the preferred value), you will need to set an explicit SQL Server Login's username and password in your Connection String.

1. Create a new Login object in the Server (you will need to login to the server first somehow, either locally or remotely using the `sa` account, if it exists)
2. Specify the new Login's credentials by replacing `Integrated Security=True` with `User Id=<userName>;Password=<password>;`

Comment: i have tried already with 192.168.1.66\SQLEXPRESS,49170 before and had the same problem

Comment: @RolandoAzevedo What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Server has not been found or not acessibe,,.... may not be configured to allow remote connections.